# multiple submit buttons and css tabpanel

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms, submit

I have a ASP.NET Ajax web query form which is made of 4 tab panels.

Each of these panels have its own textbox and Submit button so that it can perform a particular query against the database.

E.g. one is searching data by Month, another by Name...

When a form only contains ONE submit button, **if user hit the Enter key** from within the textbox, the postback is fired and all is well.

But when there are multiple submit buttons, how can I control which one is "On" and which textbox is to be taken in account.

I mean when user click on the actual Submit button all is fine (again!).
But Enter key confuses the page.

Ideally, I would like to add a CSS class to each button, and when a particular panel is on display, this class will be set "active" by means of javascript global variable.

Is there a better way?
Does one have any working sample?

Answer (score 0):

On load, try setting the Submit Button's Enabled property equal to the Panel's Visibility property.

```
Button1.Enabled = Panel1.Visible;
Button2.Enabled = Panel2.Visible;
Button3.Enabled = Panel3.Visible;
Button4.Enabled = Panel4.Visible;
```

That way only one button at a time is enabled.

Comment: That won't work from client-side, because changing active tab is a matter of javascript, not code-behind. But there might be something in your suggestion: If I change the submit button's display property to "none" in JS, may be it won't receive the click? I'll try...